# Section name from OneNote API is not updated

Tags: onenote

I renamed a section name in a notebook at OneDrive using OneNote Online.
Then, I tried GET sections API. I expected that I got the renamed section name. However I got the old section name from the response JSON in fact.

My request URL was as follows.

```
https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/notebooks/{my notebook id}/sections

* The notebook has the renamed section.
```

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2):

This is an unfortunate known bug on our end. A workaround to get this fixed is to open the notebook in any of the clients (Windows, Mac, iOS, Android) after renaming the section and then the recall will work properly. :(

Comment: Has this bug been fixed?
If not, do you have an ETA for fixing this bug?

Comment: Hi,
This bug has not been fixed yet but it is on our radar. Given the scoped-down surface area (Onenote Online only)and given it can be worked around by syncing the renamed section in Windows Desktop OneNote, this bug has been kind of low in our priority list.
But the good news is that we have determined a course of action to fix bugs of these types in the near future. So I'd expect the next major update of the APIs to include this bug fix. Cannot promise any dates but I'll try my best to get this resolved in the next quarter.
Apologies for your bad experience and thanks for keeping us honest.

Comment: It is still not working. When are you guys planning to fix this ? @DipakBoyed